# SIR Model in R: wrong y boundaries

Tags: r

I used  a `SIR model` and set the `initial conditions at S= 600, I = 1 and R=0`.
However, the `y` values do not exceed **25**, the whole model is *correct*, but the y axis is *wrong*.
This is the code:

```
library ("deSolve")

parms <- c(a=0.05, b=0.1)
inits <- c(S=600, I=1, R=0)
dt <- seq(0,100,0.1) # from 0 to 100 in steps of 0.1


SIR <- function(t,x,parms){
with(as.list(c(parms,x)),{
dS <- -a * S *I
dI <- a * S * I - b * I
dR  <- b * I
der <- c(dS, dI, dR)  # what does it mean?
list(der) # the output must be returned
}) # end of 'with'

}



SIR.out <- data.frame(ode(c(S=S, I=I, R=R), func=SIR, parms = parms, times = dt, hmax=0.01))
matplot(SIR.out[,1], sqrt(SIR.out[,-1]), type="l",col=1, lty =1:3, ylab="sqrt(No. of     Individuals)",xlab = "Years")
legend("right", c("S", "I", "R"), lty=1:3, bty = "n")
```

Can anyone help me?
Thanks in advance, Zita

Comment: Can you explain why the y-axis is wrong? What output are you expecting?

Answer (score 0):

You have your initial conditions set as `c(S=S, I=I, R=R)`, which will be pulling the values of `S`, `I`, and `R` from variables set in your global workspace (which we don't have access to, and which are probably different from the values you have in `inits`).  I suspect that if you try

```
SIR.out <- data.frame(ode(inits, func=SIR, 
                          parms = parms, 
                          times = dt, hmax=0.01))
```

(i.e. substitute `inits` for `c(S=S,I=I,R=R)`) you will find the results agree better with what you are expecting.